# List of JSF 2 events?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

So far I have only known and seen

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{situationHelper.load}"/>
```

and I wonder where I can find a list of other page (or view) events other than `preRenderView`?

Particularly, I'm looking for a event which is triggered before the binding proccess, (`preRenderView` runs after components are bound)

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help. http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/event/ComponentSystemEvent.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [tag library document](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html)  of JSF 2.1

> Name of the event for which to install a listener. The following table
>   lists the valid values for this attribute, and the corresponding event
>   type for which the listener action is registered.
>
> ```
> value for "type" tag attribute        Type of event sent to listener method
> preRenderComponent                    javax.faces.event.PreRenderComponentEvent
> preRenderView                         javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent 
> postAddToView                         javax.faces.event.PostAddToViewEvent 
> preValidate                           javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent 
> postValidate                          javax.faces.event.PostValidateEvent
> ```
>
> In addition to these values, the fully qualified class name of any java class that extends javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent may be used as the value of the "type" attribute.

So , beside the values listed above , you can also use the **fully qualified class name** of direct known subclasses of `javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent`  for the `type` tag attribute
, which can be found in the [Java docs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/event/ComponentSystemEvent.html) .

Comment: Thanks, you answer my question "a list of other page (or view) events other than preRenderView". 
However, none of them is triggered before the component being bound.

Comment: @hirikarate : You are welcome , besides these values , you can also use the fully qualified class name of any java class that extends `javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent` for the `type` tag attribute.See my update