# jsf execution order of f:events

Tags: events, jsf

What is the execution order of those?

Here is a question about possible `f:event` event names: [List of JSF 2 events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177288/list-of-jsf-2-events)

```
preRenderComponent
preRenderView
postAddToView
preValidate
postValidate
```

I want to check if a User is saved in a session bean is logged in and if not redirect to the login site, which needs to occur before view-param conversion phase since the used converter depends on the logged in User. 'preValidate' seems to take place after conversion and so I need an earlier event.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{beanA.checkLoggedIn()}"/>
<f:viewParam name="param" value="#{beanB.param}" converter="#{beanB.converter}" required="true"/>
```

I could have put 'checkLoggedIn()' in 'beanB' too, but tried to use a separate request scoped bean just for the check so that I could reuse it easily.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> *What is the execution order of those?*

- [`postAddToView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PostAddToViewEvent.html) runs right after the component is added to view during view build time (which is usually during restore view phase, but can also be during render response phase, e.g. navigation).
- [`preValidate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PreValidateEvent.html) runs right before the component is to be validated (which is usually during validations phase, but can also be apply request values phase if `immediate="true"`).
- [`postValidate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PostValidateEvent.html) runs right after the component is been validated (which is usually during validations phase, but can also be apply request values phase if `immediate="true"`).
- [`preRenderView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PreRenderViewEvent.html) runs right before the view is rendered during render response phase.
- [`preRenderComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PreRenderComponentEvent.html) runs right before the component is rendered during render response phase.

Click the links to see detailed description in javadoc introduction.

---

> *I want to check if a User is saved in a session bean is logged in and if not redirect to the login site, which needs to occur before view-param conversion phase since the used converter depends on the logged in User. 'preValidate' seems to take place after conversion and so I need an earlier event.*

You should use a simple [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for this, not a JSF event. I've posted several examples before:

- [Is there any easy way to preprocess and redirect GET requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294651/is-there-any-easy-way-to-preprocess-and-redirect-get-requests/7294707#7294707)
- [Are there some issue at inserting some check into template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062757/are-there-some-issue-at-inserting-some-check-into-template/9979178#9979178)

Comment: `preValidate`/`postValidate` are not called at all on a component in case of `immediate="true"`. Looking at Mojarra source code confirms that. Is that supposed to be like that?