# Access Non-Lazy Page Data on Primefaces Datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have a DataTable without lazy loading and paging enabled. Can I access to the requested page data before rendering for some extra modification on that specific page only ?

One can ask, why not modify before setting the data ?, because data coming from another table and requested data is already huge. Then why not go with lazyloading at all, architectural decisions. These are all valid questions, but not my question at all.

Comment: You probably want to create a custom renderer and override https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/bbfdd5958290da923dae999945fcfc6716891597/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java#L1153

Comment: probably yes, but do you think I should make some db calls during this custom renderer ?

Comment: You might want to like at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14004230/4605161

Comment: good content and may help me. thanks.