# NPE in adding composite component programmatically

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces

Getting following exception when adding composite component programmatically

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.getComponentMetadata(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:220) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:938) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:605) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:605) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:605) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:605) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.omnifaces.util.Components.includeCompositeComponent(Components.java:320) ~[omnifaces-1.6.jar:1.6]

Components.includeCompositeComponent(form,
        "ccomp", "ccomponent.xhtml", "ccomponentId");
```

NPE does not appear when `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING = true`. But when `true`, getting duplicate id errors in other places.

How to resolve this?

Comment: The full stack trace and/or a MCVE would be helpful to see the culprit. And, if you can, trying latest Mojarra too. Version 2.1.6 is more than 3 years old already.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it in a wrong phase. Try doing that in the `postAddToView` phase.

[List of JSF 2 events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177288/list-of-jsf-2-events)