# Why is f:event postValidation triggered while submitting another form on the same page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a jsf 2.2 application (myfaces 2.2.8). On a page I have multiple forms from different included (`jsf:include`) facelet files.

In one file a form is defined with a `<f:event type="postValidate"...>` tag. In another included file another form is defined with only a submit button.

Clicking on this button triggers the listener defined in `f:event`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f:event` tag isn't bound to any of the forms. It's just a tag to tell JSF to invoke a listener if an event of the declared `type` happens, no matter where in the view. So it's the expected behaviour to be invoked when any of the forms is submitted. You could anyway grab the source form into the listener:

```
public void listener(ComponentSystemEvent evt) {
    //Get the source form
    evt.getSource();
}
```

**See also:**

- [JSF `f:event` documentation](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html)
- [List of JSF 2 events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177288/list-of-jsf-2-events)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. So my JSF book is wrong about `f:event` is bound to the enclosing component.